# A question about representation between three numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I came across a question today:

Let $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}>1$ be three pairwise relatively prime integers.Let $r_{1},r_{2},r_{3}$ be the smallest positive integers such that there exist integers $$s_{ij}\ge 0,1\le i,j\le 3 ,i\not =j$$with

$$r_{1}a_{1}=s_{12}a_{2}+s_{13}a_{3}$$

$$r_{2}a_{2}=s_{21}a_{1}+s_{23}a_{3}$$

$$r_{3}a_{3}=s_{31}a_{1}+s_{32}a_{2}$$
I want to prove if $s_{13}=0$, then $s_{23}=0.$

I have tried to  prove by contradiction.
Suppose $s_{23}\not =0$, it's easy to see $r_{2}\le s_{12}$.

$if \ s_{21}>0$, then $$(r_{1}-s_{21})a_{1}=(s_{12}-r_{2})a_{2}+s_{23}a_{3}$$
contradict the minimality of $r_{1}$.
But I can't prove$s_{21}>0$, How can I do it?

Comment: Here's a hint. If $s_{13}=s_{21}=0$, then $a_2<a_3<a_1$. On the other hand, there is $r'_1<a_2$ such that $r'_{1}a_1\equiv a_3\pmod{a_2}$. You get a contradiction.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen Thanks, I got it!